# ¿Cuál es la manera correcta de guardar una imagen en Mysql con Android?

Tags: android, mysql

¿De qué manera tengo que estar guardando una imagen que subo con una app Android?

Lo que estaba elaborando era crear un File y estar guardando el File pero no sé si sea lo correcto, esa es mi duda ya que después esas imágenes que tenga en Mysql las tengo que tener en la app y estará sincronizada con una página web pero solo tengo dudas sobre la imagen.

Comment: solo guarda la ruta de la imagen en la base.

Comment: Lo correcto es guardar la ruta de la image?

Comment: Para efectos prácticos la respuesta es con el tipo de datos Blob pero recomiendo más lo que dice @Rene Limon

Answer (score 2):

La mejor opción es almacenar solo la ruta de la imagen en lugar de almacenar la imagen en la base. Tomando la traducción de [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3751/4987172):

Hay un par de cuestiones:

- El almacenamiento de la base de datos suele ser más caro que el almacenamiento del sistema de archivos.
- Puede super-acelerar el acceso al sistema de archivos con productos estándar fuera de la plataforma

  - Por ejemplo, muchos servidores web utilizan la llamada del sistema sendfile () del sistema operativo para enviar de forma asincrónica un archivo directamente desde el sistema de archivos a la interfaz de red. Las imágenes almacenadas en una base de datos no se benefician de esta optimización.
- Cosas como servidores web, etc, no necesitan ninguna codificación especial o procesamiento para acceder a las imágenes en el sistema de archivos
- Las bases de datos ganan donde la integridad transaccional entre la imagen y los metadatos es importante.

  - Es más complejo administrar la integridad entre los metadatos db y los datos del sistema de archivos
  - Es difícil (dentro del contexto de una aplicación web) garantizar que los datos se han descargado al disco en el sistema de archivos

Como dato adicional, lo que se tiene que tomar en cuenta es siempre mantener actualizadas las referencias a las imágenes que se tienen guardadas al realizar transacciones básicas: eliminar, actualizar, insertar.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Rene

Comment: Puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada si es que resolvió tu duda.

Comment: ok una pregunta mas,

Comment: En un String tengo el path pero despues lo convierto a File, segun tu informacion es mejor guardar el String que el File?

Comment: No sabia que tenia el File pero ayer me di cuenta que el path sigue en el File lo unico que cambia es de String a File

Answer (score 1):

Decidir si una imagen se debe guardar en Base de Datos o no es un gran tema y decidir siempre por el filesystem puede ser contraproducente. En palabras de Abraham Silberschatz en su libro [Fundamentos de Bases de datos](https://unefazuliasistemas.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/fundamentos-de-bases-de-datos-silberschatz-korth-sudarshan.pdf) capitulo `23.4. BASES DE DATOS MULTIMEDIA pag 579` dice:

> Sin embargo, el almacenamiento de los objetos multimedia fuera de la
>   base de datos hace más difícil proporcionar la funcionalidad de la
>   base de datos, como el indexado con base en el contenido real de datos
>   multimedia. También puede llevar a inconsistencias, como que un
>   archivo esté registrado en la base de datos pero que sus contenidos
>   falten, o viceversa. Por tanto, resulta deseable almacenar los propios
>   datos en la base de datos.

Por otra parte si almacenas muchas imagenes en base de datos:

> las características de las bases de datos se vuelven importantes
>   cuando el número de objetos multimedia almacenados es grande. Aspectos
>   como las actualizaciones transaccionales, las facilidades de consulta
>   y el indexado se vuelven importantes

y por lo tanto recomienda:

> Un enfoque de la creación de una base de datos para esos objetos
>   multimedia es utilizar las bases de datos para almacenar los atributos
>   descriptivos y realizar un seguimiento de los archivos en los que se
>   almacenan los objetos multimedia

Por otra parte `Microsoft Research` y `University of California at Berkeley` han realizado estudios y publicaron el articulo [To BLOB or Not To BLOB:
Large Object Storage in a Database or a Filesystem?](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2006/04/tr-2006-45.pdf) En el se hace una comparativa de usar el filesystem vs Base de datos y trae varias graficas de cosas a tomar en cuenta, pero en estas graficas hay un patron comun del que me he dado cuenta: Si la cantidad de archivos es poca siempre es mejor el filesystem, pero conforme la cantidad de archivos aumenta el rendimiento de la base de datos es mejor. Es decir si vas a almacenar por ejemplo 100 imagenes en 3 o 4 meses es mejor el filesystem, pero si son 100 000 imagenes en ese tiempo es mejor la base de datos.

[image: filesystem vs databases]

**Este comportamiento explica (para mi) el porque la mayoria de la gente tiene la idea de que es mejor el filesystem en vez de la base de datos, pero yo diria que depende.**

Otro punto que expone Abraham Silberschatz en otra edicion de su libro es que si la cantidad de archivos a guardar es estatica (es decir, no cambia o no se actualiza frecuentemente) es mejor usar el filesystem, pero si la cantidad de archivos es dinamica(es decir, cambia mucho, o se actualiza frecuentemente) es mejor usar la base de datos.

Tambien depende mucho que quieras hacer con la información: si piensas estar sacando reportes de las imagenes guardadas, usar el filesystem no es el enfoque adecuado ya que perderas todas las operaciones de agregación que te proporciona sql para sacar estadisticas como los `group by`, `having`, `avg`, `sum`, etc. y si no piensas sacar este tipo de reportes, es mejor el filesystem.

Si optas por el filesystem un problema que se puede presentar es la codificación de caracteres. Si en tu sistema se presenta el problema del encoding te causara problemas con los nombres de archivo y podrias no encontrar archivos que si estan almacenados al querer mostrarselos al usuario, o peor aun devolverle otro archivo.

Si optas por la base de datos, a la larga el rendimiendo se ve afectado conforme aumenta la cantidad de archivos. Por ello es mejor tener dos bases de datos una donde este tu modelo relacional con una tabla que genere un identificador para las imagenes y otra donde solo tengas una tabla con ese identificador y los archivos binarios. Esta forma tiene un costo de arquitectura mas alto, pero garantiza la integridad y el rendimiento.

*Por ultimo te dare el comentario de que un celular android o iOS tienen recursos limitados y poca capacidad de procesamiento, por eso android usa SQLite como base de datos nativa. Tener en estos sistemas conexiones duras a los grandes SMBD afecta su rendimiento y puede desesperar al usuario o darle la idea de que la aplicación no sirve, por lo que es mejor el enfoque de hacer en estos dispositivos clientes de web service y que la mayor parte del procesamiento se haga en el server.*

Espero que todo esto te sirva, saludos.