# reducir tamaño de archivo (pdf, docx, xlsx, etc) con php antes de subirlo al servidor

Tags: php, mysqli, pdf, docx

tengo un sistema web en donde subo archivos al servidor mediante un formulario..

Estos archivos pueden ser pdf, doc, docx, xls, xlsx y jpg...

Estoy buscando la forma de reducir su peso antes de que este sea subido al servidor para que la carga sea mas rápida

He navegado buscando la forma y nada.. solo hay ejemplos para archivos JPG

Acaso no existe alguna forma de hacerlo?

Espero me puedan apoyar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la API [zlib](http://www.rinconastur.com/php/php71.php) que te permite comprimir archivos por ejemplo en gzip.

Si vas a almacenar archivos en el servidor te sugiero que analices [Filesystem vs base de datos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38177/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-manera-correcta-de-guardar-una-imagen-en-mysql-con-android/38204#38204) y veas la mejor alternativa que se acomode a tu caso, para que desarrolles una mejor aplicación que te cause menos problemas.

Comment: Esta API me cambiaria la extencion de el archivo?... osea, si mi archivo es "pdf" cambiara de forma permanente a extencio "gz"?

Comment: Cambiaría a extensión gzip que puedes leer con la aplicacion 7zip en windows, pero al descomprimirlo volverías a tener tu archivo pdf o doc, según sea el caso.

Comment: Ese seria mi problema... es indispensable que la persona pueda visualizar los archivos pdf, en el navegador

Comment: Exacto al hacer la petición al servidor con php para descargar el archivo, ahi lo descomprimes y ya se lo pasas descomprimido a javascript

Comment: `$c1=gzencode($strContenidoPdf,2,FORCE_GZIP);`

Comment: a ok... ya entendi.. muchas gracias... empezare leyendo la documentacion.. para implementarlo

Comment: Con esta descomprimes `readgzfile("prueba.html.gz");` la linea anterior, viene en la pagina un ejemplo. Te recomiendo la seccion `Economizando espacio en el servidor`

Comment: Recuerda aceptar la respuesta que más te ayudó.