# Guardar archivo pdf en base de datos

Tags: java, netbeans

necesitaria que me pudieran guiar, estoy armando un proyecto y en el tengo una ventana donde deberia seleccionar un archivo pdf y a este guardarlo en la base de datos (postgresql). Al archivo deberia de convertirlo en una cadena de array y asi guardarlo, para despues realizar el paso contrario para verlo.
Busque por todos lados pero lo unico que me muestran es como guardar una imagen, intente hacerlo solo pero no me ha salido.
Si alguien tiene como hacerlo les agradezco.
Saludos

Comment: Porque no intentas almacenar solo la ruta del archivo, es decir subes el archivo a tu servidor  y obtienes la ruta donde lo almacenaste y posteriormente solo consultas por la ruta es lo mas recomendable,

Comment: Te recomiendo leer esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38177/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-manera-correcta-de-guardar-una-imagen-en-mysql-con-android/38204#38204

Comment: buenisimo, gracias

Answer (score -2):

La base datos no es para guardar archivos, sino informacion, debes investigar como guardar tu archivo en el servidor y guardar la ruta donde lo guardaste, es mas facil y apropiado

Comment: impecable, gracias