# problemas BD llena

Tags: php, base-de-datos, postgresql

mi duda es que hago cuando mi BD se llena por ejemplo yo uso postgresql y ya tengo bastante informacion, ya que se lo usa para guardar información cada 5 minutos al realizar un monitoreo continuo de la red local de la empresa, ademas tambien necesito guardar todos estos datos porque necesito llevar un historial.  Ya van 3 años corriendo el sistema, pero cada consulta que realizo la respuesta es muy lenta
¿esta bien usar ese gestor de BD?
¿como puedo solucionar esa lentitud de las consultas?
¿alguna vez desarrollaron o formaron parte de algun proyecto identico?

Comment: Mach1, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta para evitar sea cerrada**, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Te sugiero utilizar el comando `VACUUM`, que puede mejorar el desempeño de la base de dados.

**Sobre los comandos `DELETE` y `UPDATE`:**

- El comando `DELETE` no elimina los registros fisicamente de las tablas, sino que los marca como inútil por razones de rendimiento;
- El comando `UPDATE` no edita los registros fisicamente en las tablas, sino crea un nuevo registro y marca el registro antigo como inútil.

**¿Como el comando `VACUUM` puede ayudarte?**

- `VACUUM ANALYSE`: actualiza las estadisticas de almacenamiento de las tablas que van a mejorar el desempeño de las consultas;
- `VACUUM FULL`: elimina fisicamente los registros marcados como inútil, lo cual limpia la tabla. Este comando bloquea las tablas.

Más detalles en la [documentación del PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-vacuum.html) y una explicación sobre como [Compactar base de dados PostgreSQL](http://johansoft.blogspot.com.br/2007/08/compactar-base-de-datos-postgresql.html).

Comment: Saludos Victor, muchas gracias por tu aporte, sería muy bueno que del enlace obtengas la información y la agregues a tu respuesta, el motivo fundamental es el siguiente: los enlaces expiran, por ende, la respuesta deja de ser útil. Hagamos una mejor comunidad hispana de desarrolladores con todo el power 2.0!!! un abrazo :D

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentário fredyfx!

Comment: de nada hermano, vamos elevando el cosmos con todo el power 2.0!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Si cada vez que agregas información o conforme pasa el tiempo tu base de datos es mas lenta, hay varios motivos que pueden ocasionar esto pero no es que tu base de datos este llena.
Estos son algunos tips para hacerlo mas rápido:

```
Tus tablas siempre deben tener una llave entera.
Minimizar en la medida de lo posible las llaves compuestas.
Si los querys ademas de resolver por las llaves también usan otros campos en las consultas, conviene indizar dichos campos.
Las clausulas AND en la parte del where deben ir acomodados de tal forma que el primer AND obtenga el conjunto mas pequeño de datos, esto para que se resuelva el query mas rapido.
```

Te dejo esta liga que explica [como elegir llaves primarias en bases de datos](http://inmensia.com/blog/20070223/elegir_clave_primaria_tabla_base_datos_oracle.html).

Te aconsejo revisar los costos de tus querys con la sentencia [explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-explain.html) de postgres para que puedas averiguar cual(es) se tarda(n) mas y puedas indizarlos y solucionar tu problema.

Por ultimo si guardas archivos binarios en la base de datos en este hilo puedes revisar muchos [puntos a considerar para que el rendimiento de tu aplicación no se vea afectado al guardar en base de datos en en su defecto escoger el fylesystem.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38177/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-manera-correcta-de-guardar-una-imagen-en-mysql-con-android/38204#38204)

Personalmente creo que debes empezar por lo de los indices y los costos de los querys ya que es lo mas probable.